# display an alert when body background image has finished loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hey there i have the following code that sets and scales the background image in the body tag...

```
html,body {

    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url(some image);
    background-size:100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size:100% 100%;        /*  Safari  */
    -khtml-background-size:100% 100%;         /*  Konqueror  */
    -moz-background-size:100% 100%;          /*  Firefox  */
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    overflow:hidden;

}
```

what i want to do is display an alert when the image in the body finishes loading or maybe when the whole page finishes loading.. however, i've found this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/gmzSG/light/) and this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024843/wait-for-image-to-be-fully-loaded-before-displayed-on-page) on the net but it doesn't seen to fit my situation. thanks.

Comment: There is no load event for bg images.

Comment: Use window load for doing stuff when the page finishes loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. When all your content was loaded this event will trigger

```
$(window).load(function() {
 alert('loaded')
});
```

And btw u can optimize your css

```
html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size:100% 100%;        /*  Safari  */
    -khtml-background-size:100% 100%;         /*  Konqueror  */
    -moz-background-size:100% 100%;          /*  Firefox  */
    background: url(someImage) no-repeat fixed;  
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Might want to fix your brackets

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jquery, this wait until whole page is loaded and then run code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    alert( "css and graphic is loaded." );
});
```

There is no load event on background images, but there is this plugin that can detect them:
https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages

also you can chceck this similar question:
[How can I check if a background image is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057990/how-can-i-check-if-a-background-image-is-loaded)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).load(function() {
 alert("Css has been loaded/ Loaded");
});
```

This executes after your all css and js code executes completely.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [imagesloaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) jQuery plugin, and just add

`$('body').imagesLoaded(function(){
  alert('LOADED');
});`

this works for when all images within body load.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/22cPW/)